# Button hover effect pulls up paragraph beneath

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a fancy button hover state for the default button in Bootstrap 3. Basically, the button starts out with 4px of `border-bottom` and when hovered this reduces to `2px`. Because of this, I compensate with `top: 2px` on the button.

This works fine, however it's affecting other elements which I don't want it to do. For example, it pulls the paragraph beneath it up. Here's a JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kD6dQ/

You can see when you hover over the button the paragraph below changes position. How do I stop that?

I've tested this in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `top` for your element. When changed to `margin-top` it works.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kD6dQ/2/)

css:

```
.btn-default:hover {
    background: #eba22b;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #db9016;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisWhite This is a bad way to solve it. Check my answer. You shouldn't have to compensate for it. Just simply add a height.

Comment: Why is this a bad way exactly? (honest question, want to learn)

Comment: Well its not like "this will break everything" but why do it like this when the button should have a height anyway?

Comment: hmm, you've got a point there. I guess it's more a matter of taste then and not good / bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the hover declaration:

```
.btn-default:hover {
    background: #eba22b;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #db9016;
    top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kD6dQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to simply add height to `.btn-default`

**E.G:** `height: 35px;`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/kD6dQ/3/)